# Maintaining session in after closing UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, asihttprequest, hybrid

I have an application which has a login page resides on the application server. So I open a UIWebView to handle the login. After then I want to switch to the UIView and make API calls using ASIHttp library (others may also be acceptable). The problem is; after I login server keeps session object for authentication purpose, so when I close the UIWebView and switch to a UIView and make an API call, it fails. I believe, somehow I need to maintain session object (set after login) in the API calls. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use a cookie? If the server is setting a session cookie for your UIWebView, extract it and set it with the subsequent HTTP call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps I followed:

- Extract the cookies in UIWebView using `NSHTTPCookieStorage` class.
- Send it back using `ASIHTTPRequest`  `setRequestCookies:` method for the subsequent calls