# Secure, efficient way to auto log into web view in app using auth token?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

In our app the user logs in and we receive an auth token to use for rest requests.

Now we want to be able to "auto log in" users to a web interface which will be viewed through a web view in the app (UIWebView). This is so that users don't have to log in twice and it appears seamless.

One way we thought to do this was to send the auth token via a custom header when the URL is called in the Web View. We have found some limited info on this around. The web interface would then authenticate the user based on this auth token.

Is there a better way? How have other people solved it?

We are using https. Obviously we don't want to send the auth token via query string as this is very insecure.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this answer works for your problem: [Maintaining session in after closing UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017831/maintaining-session-in-after-closing-uiwebview) .

I don't recommend building ad-hoc authentication mechanisms such as sending a "special" header with the token the user sent you, echoing back this information is unnecessary.

If the token is for logging in, then I recommend using the session opened by the log in process in the rest of the HTTP calls.

Comment: The problem is that half of our requests go through the REST api, so we have an auth token for that. As long as you are logged into the app you should also be logged into the web views (multiple throughout the app). I suppose we might be able to build our own cookie and send via the Web View, but this sounds like our idea of just sending the auth token.

Comment: In that case, I think you're right, building your own cookie is the same as sending the token.
Is the REST request signed or something or it doesn't matter? Of course it's better if the connection goes through https.